# How to access a variable defined in a Listener from the main class?

Tags: java, swing, global-variables

I have a problem with a variable in `MyFrame` class. I want to have in `MyFrame` class the value of a variable that is defined in a combobox listener.

This is my situation: I have a combobox with some friends' name. I have put a listener to the combobox which has to return the surname of the selected friend.
I want to insert the value of `surname` in a command in `MyFrame` class, but there are some problems: once setted `surname` as `final` (because it has to be used in the Listener), I have an error that say:

`The final local variable surname cannot be assigned, since it is defined in an enclosing type`.

What is (or are) the matter(s)? Here I post my code:

```
public class MyFrame extends {
public static void main (String[] args)
    {
        //other 
        String [] names = {"john","al","jack"};
        final String surname=null;
        JLabel nameLbl = new JLabel("surname: " + surname);         
        JComboBox box = new JComboBox(names);    
        JPanel centralPnl = new JPanel();
        centralPnl.add(nameLbl);
        centralPnl.add(box);            
        box.addItemListener(new ItemListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent e) {                 
                if (e.getStateChange() == ItemEvent.SELECTED)
                { 
            // Here operations from database 
            //that return friends' surname under the variable name of "result"
                    surname = result;                       
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: your code is not valid, fix it please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Beyond the issues with the code already pointed out, I guess the question is do you need to store surname or are you just using it to update the label?

If you need to store the data, move your surname variable to the class level.

If you are simply updating the label, then do something like

```
nameLbl.setText("surname: " + result);
```

Answer (score 4):

You are trying to reassign a `final` variable, and thats the problem.
Also your `final` variable needs to be initialised in the first place.

Comment: Ok, but all problems are connected: I want to use a value that is returned from the listener, so I have to define the variable that will contain this value as `final`. But if I define it `final` i can't modify its value..how can i do?

Comment: you can do `nameLbl.setText(result);`

Answer (score 1):

There are two things first one is that `final` variable must be initialized when it is declared and that `final` variable cannot be reassigned a value.

Unfortunately you are doing both of the mistakes.

Another problem is that you should post a **Valid** code; it will make others finding problems easily.